# Converting the Linq to Entity from query syntax to method syntax?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have this LINQ to Entity:

```
            var de = from dm in _context.DamageEvents
                     where dm.StatusID == statusId
                     group dm by new { dm.ClientId, dm.Client.ClientName, dm.SiteId, dm.Site.Name, dm.SiteObjectId } into g
                     select new
                     {
                         g.Key.ClientId,
                         g.Key.ClientName,
                         g.Key.SiteId,
                         g.Key.Name,
                         g.Key.SiteObjectId,
                         icon = g.Select(i=>i.SiteObject.ObjectModel.ObjectType.Icon).FirstOrDefault()
                     };
```

How can I convert the linq above to from **query syntax** to **method syntax**.

Any idea how can I implement it?

Comment: Why do you want to do it?

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
var de = _context.DamageEvents.Where(dm => dm.StatusID == statusId)
                    .GroupBy(dm => new {dm.ClientId, dm.Client.ClientName, dm.SiteId, dm.Site.Name, dm.SiteObjectId})
                    .Select(g => new
                    {
                        g.Key.ClientId,
                        g.Key.ClientName,
                        g.Key.SiteId,
                        g.Key.Name,
                        g.Key.SiteObjectId,
                        icon = g.Select(i => i.SiteObject.ObjectModel.ObjectType.Icon).FirstOrDefault()
                    });
```